# Sweet Alert with form JS (3 input)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, css, sweetalert

I would like to implement a form inside of the sweet alert. I can put just one input inside, with title and body.

There is a way to customize the alert, docs says it, but is not allowed to load class css3 from my framework (customizecss.com) or from my style.css.

I'm trying to include a input inside of the alert, this way:

```
swal({
       title: "HTML <small>Title</small>!",
       text: "<input type='text'><label class='my-label'>Name</label>",
       html: true 
});
```

And it doesn't work, only show the label... why?

I wonder if there is some way to do it...

Thanks!

Sweet Alert  ->  https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this plugin in order to achive what you want:

https://github.com/taromero/swal-forms

It creates forms inside the modal in a syntax-fiendly manner:

```
 swal.withForm({
    title: 'More complex Swal-Forms example',
    text: 'This has different types of inputs',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
    confirmButtonText: 'Get form data!',
    closeOnConfirm: true,
    formFields: [
      { id: 'name', placeholder: 'Name Field' },
      { id: 'nickname', placeholder: 'Add a cool nickname' },
      { id: 'password', type: 'password' },

      { name: 'sex', value: 'Male', type: 'radio' },
      { name: 'sex', value: 'Female', type: 'radio' },

      { name: 'skills', value: 'JS', type: 'checkbox' },
      { name: 'skills', value: 'Ruby', type: 'checkbox' },
      { name: 'skills', value: 'Java', type: 'checkbox' },

      { id: 'select',
        type: 'select',
        options: [
          {value: 'test1', text: 'test1'},
          {value: 'test2', text: 'test2'},
          {value: 'test3', text: 'test3'},
          {value: 'test4', text: 'test4'},
          {value: 'test5', text: 'test5'}
        ]}
    ]
  }, function (isConfirm) {
    // do whatever you want with the form data
    console.log(this.swalForm) // { name: 'user name', nickname: 'what the user sends' }
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but I'll answer the question for all the web searchers out there:
You need to give an object as an argument, with an `html` property:

```
swal({
html: "<form action='verify.php' method='post'>
    <input id='user' type='email'>
    <input id='pass' type='password'>
    <input id='idno' type='number'>
    <submit>
</form>"});
```

Replace `verify.php` with whatever page you need the data in, and replace the string after `html:` with whatever HTML code you need.

The only downside is that people need to hit the submit-button on the form, and not SweetAlert's own button, although there might be a way to remove SweetAlert's own button too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use a Sweet Alert with a type of 'input' (as opposed to 'error' or 'warning').

```
    $window.swal({title: 'Text Entry', text: 'Put some text here, please.', type: 'input'});
```

From the Github README:
A prompt modal where the user's input is logged:

```
sweetAlert({
  title: "An input!",
  text: 'Write something interesting:',
  type: 'input',
  showCancelButton: true,
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  animation: "slide-from-top"
  }, function(inputValue){
    console.log("You wrote", inputValue);   
});
```

Comment: I didn't explain very well, I want to implement a form, with three o four inputs. I saw the documentation and I know just one input is easy

Comment: I don't believe that's possible without changing SweetAlert's code. Have you considered a generic modal?

Comment: Umm, and in the generic modal, it would be possible that my class CSS injected from my framework work?

Comment: I need more information. Are you using SharePoint? Or is there an OOCSS framework that you're using (e.g. Bootstrap)?

Comment: I am using materializecss.com

Comment: Got it! I was confused because your question mentioned customizecss.com. Materialize does offer modals:    http://materializecss.com/modals.html