# Swetalert forms in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I'm trying to use sweetalert modal with complex form. I've already read  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655649/" where is shown how to do it whit a plugin.

I wonder how can I use the plugin with sweetalert library for Drupal 8? It seems to be no match between the two filesystem folders.

Comment: Your question does not explain what specific problem you are having. Are you having trouble adding the javascript to your module or theme? Maybe read [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-theme)

Comment: You're right Pierre, sorry. I needed a way to use complex form into Sweetalert modal. I thought would be possible to do it by  installing the plugin Sweetalert Forms on Drupal Sweetalert library but i'm not sure it is compatible whit it. So I did a bit of research on the web and found a different way to solve my problem. thanks for your time.